# Custom Banno Dashboards unable to load the applications in some Android phones but working fine in all ios phones

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We have created some custom applications like Card Management/e-Alerts using symXchange and linked them to Banno. They are loading and working as expected in all ios phones but unable to load in some Android phones. I have attached the error message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4U5O.jpg)

Comment: The phrase "unable to load in some Android phones" implies that it works in some Android phones and not in others. Do you have a list of working phones + operating systems as well as a list of non-working phones + operating systems?

Comment: Separately, what is the URL and response code shown in that screenshot? The URL and response code are cut off and are not fully visible.

Comment: Working phone: Samsung S21 - Android version 13 and Non-working phone: Samsung S9 - Android version 9. URL is https://onlinebankingapi.kemba.com:8085/dynamic and there was no response code. The error says "net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"

Comment: For the phones and operating systems that fail, what happens if you visit the https://onlinebankingapi.kemba.com:8085/dynamic directly (i.e. not within the plugin UI in Banno) via the browser on the phone (probably Chrome)?

Comment: From the phone that fails through Banno, https://onlinebankingapi.kemba.com:8085/dynamic is working fine through the phone browser(chrome).

Comment: From searching on the web, one possibility for that problem could be mixing HTTPS and HTTP content. It'll be important to make sure that all content (HTML, JavaScript, CSS, images, etc) are served from HTTPS.

Comment: It did not work when removed mixing HTTPS and HTTP content. We tested Banno's Build Your First Plugin https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/quickstarts/buildyourfirstplugin/ and that did not work either. And the working phone example (Samsung S21 - Android version 13) suddenly stopped working without making any changes to the application or Android version.

Comment: Is that using the [latest commit](https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example/commit/77c699be670e154c1f27385ce03a3bbfd04cb6da) of the Simple Plugin Example?

Comment: Related, is that being run on a server or being run locally?

Comment: The latest commit of Simple Plugin Example seems to be working. It is being run on a DMZ server. There is no sample data to show that some android phones are always working or always breaking. Even without any changes on the server end, some android phones sometimes working and sometimes breaking.

Comment: Interesting. And just to clarify, by "latest commit" we are in fact both talking about https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example/commit/77c699be670e154c1f27385ce03a3bbfd04cb6da ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: That's strange. If a clear pattern emerges for operating system + device, or particular days and times, etc then that would help narrow things down.

Comment: I still couldn't figure out the pattern. It's happening randomly. For example my android phone sometimes work and sometimes doesn't without any changes on the application server.

Comment: It might be worth deleting and reinstalling the app to see if that clears out something that may have gotten 'stuck'. It's not meant to be something to do in regular habit, just speculation that might help narrow things down.

Comment: We tried deleting and reinstalling the app but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: The seeming randomness makes it appear as though the DMZ might have an issue. What happens if you remove the DMZ from the equation?

Comment: If we remove DMZ, unable to test the app outside our network.

Comment: It's worth noting that plugins are required to be [hosted from a public-facing web server](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/hosting/). By definition, plugins _must_ be accessible from outside of your network.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic error on Android and there's not enough information to diagnose the problem. It is most commonly encountered with the underlying device has a network connectivity error of some sort.

When diagnosing issues like this, general suggestions would be:

- Use a fully public URL on a standard port
- Ensure all resources are https
- Use a public network and not an internal wifi connection
- Turn of Wifi on a phone and use the cell service (or the reverse)

Comment: Tried all the possibilities but couldn't come up with a solution. The dashboards work inside a browser on the Android phone but not in the mobile app.

Comment: There are no known issues around this type of error and several million users load plugins daily. There is something specific about your specific scenario triggering this, but without more details or the ability to recreate the problem we would not know what to even look at.